# How do i get download URL once upload is done on firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to get the download URL once image upload is finished and then the downloadURL is set to my newAds.picLink(object.property) , but in this code since upload is in progress

```
newAds.update({ picLink: downloadURL });
```

is called which throws an error since downloadURL is currently not available and under progress. I have resolved this by using setTimeOut to 8 sec which lets the image to upload completely first and then downloadURL is recieved but that's not correct.

How can i create a correct callback that sets newAds.picLink = downloadURL once image is completely uploaded?

```
 addSubmitted.addEventListener('click', e => {
 const newAds = _db.ref(userID).push();
 const newAd = {
 };

const ref = firebase.storage().ref();
const file = $('#exampleInputFile').get(0).files[0];
const name = (+new Date() + '-' + file.name);
const task = ref.child(name).put(file, {contentType: file.type});

function abc() {
    task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        console.log(downloadURL);
        newAds.update({ picLink: downloadURL });
    });

    task.catch(error => {
        // Use to signal error if something goes wrong.
        console.log(`Failed to upload file and get link - ${error}`);
    });
}

setTimeout(abc,8000);
```

Comment: Where did you declare `newAds`?

Comment: @AlexIronside code updated , this all runs once submit button is clicked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Firebase documentation on uploading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress):

> ```
> var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/rivers.jpg').put(file);
>
> // Register three observers:
> // 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
> // 2. Error observer, called on failure
> // 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
> uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
>   // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
>   // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
>   var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
>   console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
>   switch (snapshot.state) {
>     case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
>       console.log('Upload is paused');
>       break;
>     case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
>       console.log('Upload is running');
>       break;
>   }
> }, function(error) {
>   // Handle unsuccessful uploads
> }, function() {
>   // Handle successful uploads on complete
>   // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
>   uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
>     console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
>   });
> });
> ```

So this registers a `state_changed` observer. When the upload has completed, this calls `StorageReference.getDownloadURL()` to get the download URL.

Comment: Thanks alot @Frank

Comment: The UploadTask returned by `put()` also works like a Promise, so you can use `then()` on it to continue processing after the upload completes.

Answer (score 2):

[put()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put) returns an [UploadTask](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask), which you can use like a normal promise, because it declares a [then()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then) method:

```
const task = ref.child(name).put(file, {contentType: file.type});
task.then(snapshot => {
    ref.getDownloadURL().then(...);
});
```