# code for getting the url picture in storage and put in database of firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```js
var selectedFile;

$("#file").on("change", function(event) {
 selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
 $("#uploadButton").show();
});

function uploadFile() {
 // Create a root reference
 var filename = selectedFile.name;
 var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/dogImages/' + filename);
 var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile);

 // Register three observers:
 // 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
 // 2. Error observer, called on failure
 // 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
 uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
   // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
   // See below for more detail
 }, function(error) {
   // Handle unsuccessful uploads
 }, function() {
   // Handle successful uploads on complete
   // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
   var postKey = firebase.database().ref('Posts').push().key;
   var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
   
   var postData = {
    url: downloadURL,
    caption: $("#imageCaption").val()
   };
   
   var updatess = {};
   updatess ['Posts' + postKey]  = postData;
   
   return firebase.database().ref().update(updatess);
 });

}
```

The Error is Uncaught (in promise) Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'Posts-LRyHOS3r8-VP-7WMsCS.url' and it doesnt store in database of firebase. this is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit: `downloadURL` seems to be `null`. If you search for recent questions about this, you'll see that the download URL is now retrieved asynchronously by calling `getDownloadURL()`.

So something like:

```
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
  // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
  // See below for more detail
}, function(error) {
  // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function() {
  var postKey = firebase.database().ref('Posts').push().key;
  var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
  return storageRef.getDownloadURL().toPromise().then(downloadUrl => {
    var postData = {
      url: downloadUrl,
      caption: $("#imageCaption").val()
    };

    var updatess = {};
    updatess ['Posts' + postKey]  = postData;

    return firebase.database().ref().update(updatess);
  });     

});
```

Also see:

- [the Firebase documentation sample on uploads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress)
- [the Firebase documentation on downloading files by URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url)
- [How do i get download URL once upload is done on firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463596/how-do-i-get-download-url-once-upload-is-done-on-firebase-storage/51465870#51465870)
- [Firebase get Download URL after successful image upload to firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714007/firebase-get-download-url-after-successful-image-upload-to-firebase-storage/52127282#52127282)
- [I can't get image downloadUrl from Firebase Storage (Angular/Ionic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231025/i-cant-get-image-downloadurl-from-firebase-storage-angular-ionic)