# I want to display the uploaded image to the html image tag

Tags: html, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am uploading the image to the firebase storage. the image is uploading correctly and I want to display the image in the HTML image tag. I have written a code but this doesn't seem to work out. please help.

```
 <img id="profile-img-tag" class=" circle img" src="" width="150px" height="150px">
function(){
    var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    console.log('imageUrl',downloadURL);
    // var picurl = downloadURL;
    // console.log('picurl',picurl);
    //document.getElementById('profile-img-tag').src = picurl;
    document.getElementById('profile-img-tag').src =downloadURL;
})
```

**UPDATE following comments to answers below**

HTML code below

```
<form id="upduserform">
            <img id="profile-img-tag" class=" circle img" src="" width="150px" height="150px">
            <label class="upload-group" id="uploadlabel"><b>Upload Profile Picture</b>

                <input type="file" class="upload-group" id="file">
            </label>
            <script>
                    function readURL(input) {
                   if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                       var reader = new FileReader();

                       reader.onload = function (e) {
                           $('#profile-img-tag').attr('src', e.target.result);
                       }
                       reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                   }
               }
               $("#file").change(function(){
                   readURL(this);
               });
                   </script>
        <table id="accList">  
        </table>
        <div>
        <button type="button" id="editBtn" onclick="turnOnEdit()" class="waves-effect waves light btn editpos">EDIT</button>
        <button type="submit" onclick="turnOffEdit() " id="updBtn" class="waves-effect waves light btn updpos">UPDATE</button>   
        <button type="button" class="waves-effect waves light btn closepos" onclick="closeMypro()">CLOSE</button>      
        </div>
    <!-- <a onclick="M.toast({html: 'I am a toast'})" class="btn">Toast!</a> -->

    </form>
```

javascript code below.

```
var selectedFile
$("#file").on("change", function(event){
    selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    $("#uploadbtn").show();
})
const updemp = document.querySelector('#upduserform');
updemp.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
var fileName = selectedFile.name;
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("/ProfilePictures/'" + auth.getUid() + "' /" + fileName); 
var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile);
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){

}, function(error){

}, function(){

    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
        console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
        document.getElementById('profile-img-tag').src = downloadURL;
     });

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the [`getDownloadURL()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference.html#get-downloadurl) method is asynchronous and returns a Promise that resolves with the download URL.

You therefore need to do as follows:

```
uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
   console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
   document.getElementById('profile-img-tag').src = downloadURL;
});
```

---

By doing

```
var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
document.getElementById('profile-img-tag').src = downloadURL;
```

on the second line, the value of `downloadURL` will be `undefined` because the code in this line does not wait the Promise to be resolved.

---

Want to read more about Promises and the `then()` method? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: but when I refresh the web page the image in the below tag does not appear.<img id="profile-img-tag" class=" circle img" src="" width="150px" height="150px">

Comment: What do you get in the console for `console.log('File available at', downloadURL);`?

Comment: iam getting the url of the image which has been uploaded!

Comment: everything works fine until I refresh the web page, then the image won't appear in the image tag.

Comment: Probably the call to `getDownloadURL()` is not triggered when you reload the page. You should add to your question the entire HTML and JavaScript code. Without that it is difficult to debug.

Comment: From what I can see in your code the `getDownloadURL()` method is triggered only when you submit your form (`const updemp = document.querySelector('#upduserform');
            updemp.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {})`). So you should trigger it when you reload the page I guess (but I am not sure you will have the URL since your receive it after uploading the image..). Note that you should take care to correctly indent your code: it makes it easier to read and to find bugs!

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
document.getElementById('profile-img-tag').src ="downloadURL";
```

into this:

```
document.getElementById('profile-img-tag').src = downloadURL;
```

`downloadURL` is a variable that contains the url of the image, therefore remove the `quotations`

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463596/how-do-i-get-download-url-once-upload-is-done-on-firebase-storage